# Глагол от слова "вежливость"

Tags: словообразование

На примере "...любезничать и вежличать/вежливочать"?

Comment: @N3ver_Again, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Когда-то был глагол ведать (ведать правила хорошего тона), теперь  глагол в этом значении не употребляется, только ведать - знать, чтобы не путать вежливый - сведущий. Да и необходимости в нём нет, есть много других слов и оборотов -  и русских, и заимствованных: любезничать, деликатничать и др.

Answer (score 0):

Уважить; уважать, если отношение устойчиво.

Comment: Уважать и вежливый - не однокоренные, это заимствование из польского. Ему родственны важный, уважение, отвага.

Comment: "любезничать" (других слов не воспроизведу), лебезить - суть человекоугодничество. Уважение произрастает из чувства важности поступка или самого человека.